# How to determine if tests are running local or on the remote server

Tags: java, selenium, serenity-bdd

According to this [tutorial](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/best-practices-tips-selenium-file-upload), I am able to upload files on the website while running my tests locally and on the remote server.

---

As in the tutorial is:

> For those of you doing this locally, all you need to do is use the
>   sendKeys command to type the local path of the file in any file field.
>   This works like a charm in all drivers. When moving this test to a
>   remote server (such as, for example, our Selenium 2 Cloud), all you
>   need to do is use the setFileDetector method to let WebDriver know
>   that you’re uploading files from your local computer to a remote
>   server instead of just typing a path.

on the remote server I have to use:

```
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
...
upload.sendKeys("/Path/to/image.jpg");
```

and local just:

```
upload.sendKeys("/Path/to/image.jpg");
```

And this all works fine. Only the problem is, that there is no information how to determine if my tests are running local or on the remote server.

---

I have tried to determine instance of the webDriver:

```
WebDriver proxiedWebDriver = ((WebDriverFacade) getDriver()).getProxiedDriver();
if (proxiedWebDriver instanceof RemoteWebDriver) {
    ((RemoteWebDriver)proxiedWebDriver).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
}
```

but it seems like both(local and remote) cases are using `RemoteWebDriver` while running, because in every case I'm passing `if` condition.

How can I determine if my tests are running local or remote?

Comment: you can debug the code, see where it goes, check the logs, you can force staying local by mocking services, or providing local endpoints in your test-properties files, ...

Comment: You want the address of the hub or nodes?

Comment: @RafałLaskowski address, I think would be enough.

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov Check my answer and let me know if it's helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the address of the remote server you can use `HttpCommandExecutor` like this:

```
HttpCommandExecutor ce = (HttpCommandExecutor) ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).getCommandExecutor();
String remoteAddress = ce.getAddressOfRemoteServer().toString();
String localAddress = null;

try (Socket socket = new Socket()) {
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("google.com", 80));
    localAddress = socket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (remoteAddress.contains("localhost") || remoteAddress.contains(localAddress)) System.out.println("Local machine");
else System.out.println("Remote machine");
```

The above code gets the Remote Server address (HUB) and compares it with your public IP address. It should give you the information if you are running local or remote server

Comment: And then, compare it with your local IP

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov I will edit my answer anyway and provide the way to compare IP addresses. Give me a minute

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov Check the enhanced solution :)

Comment: I think we could also check the local IP address, just in case, but I think anyone who needs this kind of solution will know how to check local IP address